# How to Check if JAI and Java3D is installed in PC or Laptop?

Tags: java, java-3d, jai

I made Desktop app with netbeans platform in java.In my app i using JAI and Java3d. This app i made for dentist. So every installation time doctore do not want to inastall jai, java3D, its like headache for dentist. So i have to check at starting of my app that if JAI and Java3D is installed or not? if not then install JAI and Java3D programetically from my app. So how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class ClassUtils {
  public static boolean isAvailable(String className) {
    boolean isFound = false;
    try {
       Class.forName(className, false, null);
       isFound = true;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       isFound = false;
    }
    return isFound;
  }

  public static boolean isJava3dAvailable() {
   return isAvailable("javax.media.j3d.View");
  }

  public static void  main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println ("JAI " +
       (ClassUtils.isAvailable("javax.media.jai.ImageJAI")?"present":"missing"));
    System.out.println ("Java3d " +
       (ClassUtils.isJava3dAvailable()?"present":"missing"));
  }

}
```

Comment: thanks its works well. now how can i execute or install java3d from myapp if it is not installed that pc or laptop? or which command i have to type or programetically install jai from my app?

Comment: This is not easy since each supported plateform has its own redistributable binary package ( http://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html ).